# When can we use 'draw upon' instead of 'draw on' and why?

Tags: prepositions

LEXICO defines ***[draw on](https://www.lexico.com/definition/draw_on)*** as follows:

> 1 (**draw on something**) Use one's experience, talents, or skills as a resource.
>
> ‘*Sue has a lot of past experience to draw on*’

> 2 (of a period of time) pass by and approach its end.
>
> ‘*he remembered sitting in silence with his grandmother as evening drew on*’

> 3 (**draw something on, draw on something**) Put an item of clothing on.
>
> ‘*he drew on his dressing gown*’

> 4 (**draw on something**) Suck smoke from a cigarette or pipe.
>
> ‘*she drew heavily on her cigarette*’

Why is it that only in 1 can we use *upon* instead of *on*?

> *Sue has a lot of past experience to draw **upon***
>
> **he remembered sitting in silence with his grandmother as evening drew **upon***
>
> **he drew **upon** his dressing gown*
>
> **she drew heavily **upon** her cigarette*

Comment: I, much to my shame, frequently draw upon cigarettes.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Are you sure that sounds fine to your ears? Note that "draw/drew upon a cigarette/cigarettes" return only a handful results.

Comment: _Journal of the Royal Society of Medicine_ Volume 84 May 1991 "The Practice of Speech after Laryngectomy" - From the moment
of birth the action of sucking is natural to every
human being, and so a large teatfrom a baby'sfeeding
bottle can be sucked upon by the patient, to make him
realize how he can take air into the mouth.
A drinking straw can also be used and if the patient
was a smoker, so too can he be reminded of how he
**drew upon a pipe or cigarette**. All these are sucking
by the mouth and not an intake of breath.

Comment: You should note *evening drew **on** (adverb)*; *She drew **on** (preposition) her cigarette.* -- In broad terms, "**upon**" (a preposition, not an adverb) is more formal in all contexts than "on". -- Thus **upon** cannot substitute for adverbial **on**

Comment: On the other hand, the idiomatic form "put upon" (meaning "burdened [by or with something]") doesn't work when changed to "put on": "Don't act so put upon."

Comment: A Google Books search for "draw upon" gives a load of 19th-century financial documents; some usages which appear clearly wrong ("draw upon a road" should surely be "draw up on a road" with the phrasal verb "draw up"); surprisingly few about "drawing upon inner qualities"; and some about drawing diagrams upon surfaces, especially vertical surfaces such as blackboards. A wide range of usages, in other words.

Answer (score -1):

Drew *upon* is best reserved for abstract resources, like "She drew upon her vast understanding of history."

Comment: "Draw upon a blackboard" seems common and that's certainly not abstract. I think it's because the blackboard is high up.

Comment: "Draw upon a blackboard" makes perfect sense, but in my experience it is not at all common.

Comment: I just checked this by googling. The web pages that include "Draw on a blackboard" but not "Draw upon a blackboard" are said to number 53,800. By contrast, the web pages that include "Draw upon a blackboard" but not "Draw on a blackboard" are said to number 3.